# Another way to saying "As part of"?

Tags: grammar, synonyms, sentence

I am looking for a synonym for 'as part of', I want to say something like this: 'As part of his plan..... he did this...'. Also, just out of curiosity should/can I be starting a sentence with 'as part of'.

Answer (score 2):

"Murdering sister Sally was **intrinsic to** his plan to gain control of the family trust." Other illegalities were required as well. All in all, a clever scheme, and he would have pulled it off too, except for those darn kids.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context of the document and who the audience is, but in general it is better to start the sentence with the main clause, and then modify it, particularly if the modifying clause is either long, or contains critical information.

I would prefer:

“The mayor recommended that bike paths be expanded across the city, as part of his plan to increase the quality of life for more residents who don’t wish to drive.”

Over:

“As part of his plan to increase the quality of life for more residents who don’t wish to drive, the mayor recommended that bike paths be expanded across the city.”

Although in political writing / speeches / media releases, the structure is often of the second kind, in order to emphasis the benefits of a proposed action or policy, while leaving "the sting in the tail" until the end.

Can’t immediately think of a better term than “As part of …”. “A component of …”, or “An element of …”, or “A central theme of …”, depending on the precise meaning you are seeking.

Comment: I definitely prefer the latter.  Your first one shouldn't have a comma either.

Comment: I would include the comma myself, to improve readability across two long clauses, but I take your point. I would still prefer the first, partly based on a journalistic background with quite definite "rules" about having the key information first (in case you are subbed to shorten the piece).